# Solving $x^x=y^y$

Tags: education

In the equation $x^x=y^y$, how do you solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ when $y$ is not $x$?

There is a small curve in the first quadrant which is not $y=x$.
graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l1jempmhhg

Comment: It doesn't look [easy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+y:+y%5Ey%3Dx%5Ex)